# Dart Editor freezes when saving files?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Everytime I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> in Dart Editor the application freezes for several seconds, sometimes up to half a minute. After that it says `Build completed successfully` in the Tools Output.

I have a habit of constantly saving my work. Having that operation take so long is aggravating, to say the least. It makes the editor almost unusable to me.

<strike>Is there any way to disable the automatic on-save build?</strike>

**EDIT 1:**

Stopping Pub Serve helped in some cases, but the editor still froze every other time, eventhough `Build completed successfully` did not appear in the Tools Output. It seems that **Refreshing workspace** was taking really long.

Since I could not remember this problem ever being so severe I looked into my older projects to find anything I did differently. In fact this time I put my sources into the `/lib` folder and referenced them via `packages:<myproject>/<myproject>.dart`. Surprisingly moving the `/lib` to `/web/lib` and importing via `lib/<myproject>.dart` instead seems to have fixed the freezing issue. Any ideas why that might be?

**EDIT 2:**

My system:

- Dart Editor version 1.9.3.release (STABLE)

  - Dart SDK version 1.9.3
- Lenovo IdeaPad Y510p

  - Intel Core i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
  - 8GB RAM
- Windows 8.1 Pro

Comment: This is weird because `../lib/<myproject>.dart` is an invalid import path. You shouldn't "walk" outside a package top-level directory in import paths (except in html-imports in Polymer where no `package:` exists). You didn't provide more information about your Dart version and OS.

Comment: This was an error on my part when writing the edit. Fixed the question and added system specs.

Comment: I see. Perfectly fine as far as I am aware to have a `lib` folder in `web`. You can try to disable the analyzis server in the DartEditor settings. I think you should create a bug report at http://dartbug.com. I'm sure they are interested in your experience. Please crosslink the issue and this SO question.

Comment: I will investigate further and try if I can isolate the issue. Then I will create the report. As usual, thanks for lightning-fast support.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is `pub serve` running in background which recognizes file changes and rebuilds. In the tools output window top-right corner is an icon with the tooltip `Stop Pub Serve` which allows you to stop it. `pub serve` is automatically launched when you run a Dart web application from DartEditor.

I don't use DartEditor a lot (mostly WebStorm since a few months) but `pub serve` should not block DartEditor.

Can you provide more information about your

- Dart version
- Hardware
- OS

Consider creating a bug report at http://dartbug.com